# ClusterR with multiple raster stacks

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster

Here is an example that raster library  provides for using clusterR and overlay functions:

```
library(raster)
beginCluster()
r <- raster()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- stack(r, r*2, r*3)
f2 <- function(d,e,f) (d + e) / (f * param)
param <- 122
ov <- clusterR(s, overlay, args=list(fun=f2), export='param')
```

I want to know how to run that function if I have multiple raster stacks:

```
s <- stack(r, r*2, r*3)
s2 <- stack(r*2, r*3, r*4)
s3 <- stack(r*3, r*4, r*5)
```

I want something like this (`d,e,f` in function `f2` are each layer in `s, s2` and `s3`):

```
ov <- clusterR(s,s2,s3, overlay, args=list(fun=f2), export='param')
```

Comment: list the stacks and loop the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would create a dummy raster layer in your stack holding the `param`value. Thus, the operations can be vectorized:

```
p <- 122
rp <- r
rp[] <- p
s <- stack(s, rp)
s2 <- stack(s2, rp)
s3 <- stack(s3, rp)
```

Then you change your function like this:

```
f2 <- function(x) (x[[1]] + x[[2]]) / (x[[3]] * x[[4]])
```

Thus, the layers of the individual stack `x` are referred to correctly. The 4th layer is the `param` value (here `p`)

Then you create a list of layer stacks:

```
stackList <- list(s, s2, s3)
```

then you `lapply` the `clusterR` function.

```
ov <- lapply(stackList, function(x){clusterR(x, fun = f2, progress = "text")})
```

`ov` will then be a list of your overlaid layers.